# How to properly refresh a PartialView in Razer page .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a simple page that also includes a PartialView so that I can refresh the data every 10 seconds  returned by the PartialView. It really is a trivial task but I'm not proficient enough with the whole web part and especially JavaScript.

How can I run the LoadData() Method every X seconds so that my partialView shows the data?

I have found the following JS code which I think should be able to refresh the PartialView but I don't know how to adapt this to my situation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    setInterval(loadTable, 1000);  // invoke load every second
    loadTable(); // load on initial page loaded
});

function loadTable() {
    $('#data').load('/controller/tabledata');
}
</script>
```

My index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@page
@model IndexModel


<div class="data">
    <partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_BezoekersData.cshtml" />   
</div>
```

The indexModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using PnP.Framework;
using System.Security;


namespace MyNameSpace.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

    public IActionResult OnGetPartial() => Partial("\\Shared\\_BezoekersData.cshtml");

    // properties left out for clarity
    public void OnGet()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
       // dataRetrieval part here. 
    }

    }
}
```

_BezoekersData.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div style="position:fixed; left:65px; top:25px; color:#c2a149; font-size:75px;  ">@Model.Vestiging</div>
<div style="position:fixed; left:1100px; top:180px; color:#c2a149; font-size:50px">@Model.MaxAantal</div>
<div style="position:fixed; left:1100px; top:285px; color:#c2a149; font-size:50px">@Model.HuidigAantal</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more function to call the partial view and refresh it, check this:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        LoadData();
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        MyModel=new MyModel {thetime=DateTime.Now };
    }

    public PartialViewResult OnGetMyPartial()   // extra method to get data
    {
        MyModel = new MyModel { thetime = DateTime.Now };
        return Partial("_BezoekersData", MyModel);
    }
```

**View:**

Mind it must be ** div id="data"**, because you use #data to call jquery function.

Pass model data to partial, add **model** attribute.

And to call the new method, using **handler**:

```
In main view:  @Model.MyModel.thetime
<div id="data">  
<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_BezoekersData.cshtml" model="Model.MyModel"/> //add a model attribute 
</div>


@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(loadTable, 1000);  
        loadTable(); 
    });

    function loadTable() {
        $('#data').load("/Index?handler=MyPartial");  //handler to call razor method
    }
</script>
}
```

**This is the partial view:**

```
@model He621.Models.MyModel

In partial:<div style="position:fixed; left:65px; top:100px; color:#c2a149; font-size:75px;  ">@Model.thetime</div>
```

**Result:**

The time refreshes every 1 seconds, and will only refresh the partial:

[image]